# Not able to convert Dataframe Float to Integer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have searched and found many options however each of these are giving me similar error.

**My Code:**
[image]

**Error**

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '43406.05000000'
```

**Things I have already tried:**

- test['Open'] = test['Open'].astype('int')
- test['Open'] = test['Open'].apply(np.int64)

Kindly help me out, thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to convert a float string to a numeric integer?

Comment: @Corralien to use the values with a library and it only takes integer values as an input.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably convert all your columns to integer in once.

Try:

```
test = pd.read_sql('BTCUSDT', engine, index_col='Time').astype(int)
```

**Update**

It would be probably better to use `round` before downcasting to `int` to avoid truncate your number:

```
>>> int(float('3.99'))
3

>>> int(round(float('3.99')))
4
```

So, prefer:

```
test = pd.read_sql('BTCUSDT', engine, index_col='Time') \
         .astype(float).round().astype(int)
```